# How to right realize Sonic "Landing"?

Tags: python, pygame

I almost created the first game in Python, so I correct shortcomings. I added part of code in function `def update(self)` to improve `Sonic` Landing. the program shows error. What's wrong?

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #[...]

    def update(self):
        hits_4 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform4)
            if self.vel.y > 0:        
                if hits_4:
                    if self.pos.y < hits_4[0].rect.bottom:               
                        self.pos.y = hits_4[0].rect.top +1
                        self.vel.y = 0
    def jump(self):
        hits4 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, platform4)
        if hits4:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 2
```

*`Platform4` isn't iterable sprite.
Error:   `File "C:\Users\дом\My project\Survival_with_Sonic.py", line 149, in update if self.pos.y < hits_4[0].rect.bottom: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: `pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform4)` probably returns a boolean, which you're then trying to modify. Did you mean to check `platform4`'s properties instead of `hits_4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.collide_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) returns `True` or `False`:

```py
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform4):
    if 0 < self.pos.y < platform4.rect.bottom:               
        self.pos.y = platform4.rect.top +1
        self.vel.y = 0
```